# What is best solution use VUEX (nuxt.js) for CRUD operators with API?

Tags: model-view-controller, axios, nuxt.js, vuex, crud

What is the best solution for deleting, editing, retrieving, and creating a record using VUEX and AXIOS?
I think this is what is the best and most logical architecture?
If it's possible give me examples
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to reason about your Vuex modules is to think of them as representations of your various resources, often represented by models on your backend. For example, you could have a `user` module, an `article` module or a `movie` module, depending on your application.

Then, you will probably need an action for each CRUD operation. For `R`, read, you might want to use two: one for fetching a single entry and another for fetching a list of items.

Let's say you're working with movies. You'd most likely need five actions that could be named as follows: `fetchMovies`, `fetchMovie`, `createMovie`, `updateMovie`, `deleteMovie`.

Each of these would have to be `async` actions where you would `await` a response from your `axios` calls.

Once you have the responses, you need to set up relevant mutations for each of these actions where you can modify the state accordingly.

This is a very rudimentary description of what your approach might be and Vuex and Nuxt are both rather flexible.

I recommend you read through the Vuex documentation and the Vuex-related sections of the Nuxt documentation, both are very well written and cover much more than what I could here.

Comment: I found this link and I going to test that.
https://codingshiksha.com/vue/vue-js-todo-crud-app-using-vuex-state-management-library-and-jsonplaceolder-rest-api-full-project-for-beginners-in-2020/
I think this can be useful